# MySQL Create Table Error?? Version problems maybe?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1005

I am getting the following from the mysql_error():

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near -->'assets' ('assetid' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY('assetid'<-- at line 1

I've also tried something like this :

```
'assets' ('assetid' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

...but with no luck.  The mysql version is 5.0.7.

### EDIT:

Actually, I've tried it without (') first before putting it.  The code is dynamic, but these are the examples:

```
CREATE TABLE 'assets' (
   'assetid' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY('assetid'),
    'rfid' VARCHAR( 128 ) ,
    'createddate' DATE ,
    'modifieddate' DATE ,
    'curlocid' INT( 11 ) ,
    'type' VARCHAR( 128 ) ,
    'brand' VARCHAR( 128 ) ,
    'name' VARCHAR( 128 ) ,
    'condition' VARCHAR( 128 ) 
);
```

### EDIT 2:

Just now I tried changing all the single quotes ( ' ) with back ticks ( ` ).. Other error occurred..

> Can't create table 'mydb.assets' (errno: 121)

Is this better or worse?

### EDIT 3:

I tried to create it using different table names and guess what? It works! Gosh, why can't I create table name 'assets'?? is it because there is some leftovers for previous operation?? if so how to I clean it?? what if i said that i delete the table by deleting it's file??(frm,myd,myi)(not drop it, due to laziness).. how do i fix it?

Comment: could we see the full query you are trying to run please while the error is very useful we will still need to see the rest of the query;

Comment: you say the code is dynamic does that mean that assets and assetid are example name and if so are those examples of ones that actually error or did you just make that one up  ?

Comment: assetid until curlocid is predefined.. Others are user entered value.. The examples i gave is the one that produces the error. I output the query alongside the mysql_error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is old but I just going to tell the answer on how to resolve this. In case someone stumbled upon it.. In this case, it's the default ENGINE that is used. I haven't noticed it until now, that the server i'm using (Z-WAMP) configure INNODB as it's default engine. After I changed it to MyISAM, which is the default engine for mysql, everything works perfectly!! however, thanks for the guys who are helping me out..

In this file --> my.cnf, change this line:

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see all your code.

Bit based on what I'm seeing, you need to eliminate all those ticks. This should work:

```
create table assets ( 
      assetid  int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key 
);
```

I ran this fine in MySQL Server 5.5

Comment: I've tried it without those ticks before.. I've updated the question for sql query..

Comment: just because correcting one mistake doesn't fix the program, doesn't mean that it wasn't a mistake. It just means its not your only mistake.

Answer (score 1):

ok so I'm not sure what is going hon here but I copied and pasted your code and got the same error so I copied line by line still broke in places it should have so I typed it out line by line had to fiddle a bit but I got it then except "condition' which may be a reserved word but I shortend it heres what i got

```
create table assets ( 
     assetid  int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    primary key(assetid),
    rfid varchar(128),
    createddate DATE,
    modifieddate DATE,
    curlocid INT(11),
    type varchar(128),
    brand varchar(128),
    name varchar(128),
    cond varchar(128)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use back ticks (`) instead of single quotes (') when quoting table or column names.